# How can I resize a column in a DataGridView using the GUI in VS2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, datagridview

When I have a DataGridView on a Windows Form, is there a way to use my mouse to simply drag a column to a proper width, instead of doing it programmatically or by manually typing in the size?

[Edit] This question is referring to design-time editing of a column width.

Comment: yes by default it can be resized with your mouse... click on the header of the column end, and drag...

Comment: When I click on the grid, my mouse cursor changes to the mover icon (4 arrows). If I click on the column header, or the edge of the column, the mouse cursor remains the mover icon. Dragging anything just moves the entire grid on the form.

Comment: I dont think so, maybe Abdul needs to clarify how it is done, from what i know, you cant readjust as if it is an excel table for example.

Comment: one thing i admit is that i am the most stupid person, what i assumed from the question is that Kurt Boyer is talking about run time,... realy sorry for that, the answer is "No"

Comment: Abdul, I've just edited my question so that it refers to design-time. It is easy to see how my original question could be misinterpreted. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there simply is no support for this.

Most likely because it was considered unnecessary.
Tweaking the numbers (Width and FillWeight) is much more productive.